# creating a log for changed local admin password script Powershell

Tags: powershell

Please help me come up with a script that does this via Powershell I got the password change part down I just need help making the log.

I want the script to be able to silently push or edit local admin passwords for Usertech and support and change the password to a complex password we set in the script.

we will roll it out via RMM to our client machines. I plan on rolling this out Monday via RMM.

I believe the script should not only have the ability to set/change the local admin passwords to those two accounts, but also save an update to a log file on a server that the machine is updated successfully so we have some output of whether it failed or it was successful.

Example: save a log to \ctdc01\install\pwupdate.txt

Content of log should read something along the lines of:

Successfully changed pw on hostname TESTHOST1.harristrucking.local.

```
$NewPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "*****" -AsPlainText -Force

>> Set-LocalUser -Name support-Password $NewPassword

 

Attempted to add- Function

 

Log-Message(

[String]

$Message

)

{

    

Add-Content

 

-Path

 

"C:\Temp\Log.txt"

 

$Message

}

 

Log-Message 

"Beginning exeuction of the script:"

Log-Message 

"Exeucting of the script..."

Log-Message 

"Completed exeuction of the script!"​

 

but it didn't work doing further research
```

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: I want to be able to change local admin passwords via powershell and generate a log

Comment: That's a statement of what you want to achieve. Which part of it do you have a problem with? Be sure to read this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I want help writing a script via powershell that does this. I'm sorry I see now I was unclear

Comment: Basically all of it I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to writing powershell scripts

Comment: Sure, we all start somewhere, but at the same time SO is not a code writing service. You need to ask a specific question. You say "but it didn't work", at least tell us what happened and any error messages you got.